# UITapGestureRecognizer doubletap still triggers singletap action

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have an UIView with both single and double tap recognizers but with different actions of course. The single tap recognizer works well but the double tap recognizer still calls and triggers the single tap...

Below is my implementation:-

```
    let singleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(toggleIsVisible))
    singleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    self.addGestureRecognizer(singleTapGesture)

    let doubleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(test))
    doubleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    self.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGesture)

    singleTapGesture.require(toFail: doubleTapGesture)
    singleTapGesture.delaysTouchesBegan = true
    doubleTapGesture.delaysTouchesBegan = true
```

Note: "self" is a UIView class

Comment: show the `test` method

Comment: hi @jawadAli, my test method works fine, its just that when I double tap my single tap is still triggered, which means the singleTapGesture.require(toFail: doubleTapGesture) doesn't really work

Comment: Your code works for me, too, with or without the last two lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it like this as well ... add delay to your single tap to check if its double tap.. if double tap then cancel performance of single tap .. simple methodology

```
var tapCount = 0
    func tapGestureRecognizer() {
        tapCount += 1
        switch (tapCount)
        {
        case 1: //single tap
            self.perform(#selector(singleTap), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.2)
        case 2: //double tap
            
            
            NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self, selector: #selector(singleTap), object: nil)
            
            doubleTap()
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        if (tapCount>2){
            tapCount = 0
        }
    }
    
    
    @objc func singleTap(){
        
    }
    
    @objc func doubleTap() {
        
    }
```

Comment: my double tap works ok just my single tap is called even when i double tapped

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine without triggering the `singleTap` gesture for `doubleTap` events. So why is the `singleTap` event gesture triggering for `doubleTap` event? Are you sure these are the only gestures you're adding? Make sure you're not adding any other customisation that might alter the gesture events. You don't need these lines:

```
singleTapGesture.delaysTouchesBegan = true
doubleTapGesture.delaysTouchesBegan = true
```

Comment: hi i have removed those lines but my single tap is still triggered when i double tap

Comment: Are you sure these are the only gesture related code that you're adding to this view? Try it out with just this code in a new project and your code will work just fine.